# in my local host checkcbox working properly but in dev check box is shrinked and it is not working

Tags: html, css, nestjs, ejs

in my local host while converting ejs to pdf checkcbox style was correct but in dev check box is shrinked and it is not showing the checked are not checked while converting ejs file to pdf how to fix it in nodejs based on conditions

```
.checked-checkbox {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 9pt;
        height: 9pt;
        border: 0px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12pt;
        line-height: 11pt;
      }
      .unchecked-checkbox {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 13pt;
        height: 13pt;
        border: 0px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12pt;
        line-height: 11pt;
      }



 <p
                class="TableParagraph"
                style="
                  margin-top: 0.05pt;
                  margin-right: 0in;
                  margin-bottom: 0in;
                  margin-left: 17.6pt;
                  margin-bottom: 0.0001pt;
                  text-indent: -11.5pt;
                  line-height: 9.8pt;
                  mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
                  mso-list: l16 level1 lfo45;
                  tab-stops: 17.6pt 101pt;
                "
              >
                <!--[if !supportLists]--><span
                  style="
                    font-size: 8pt;
                    font-family: 'Segoe UI Symbol', sans-serif;
                    mso-fareast-font-family: 'Segoe UI Symbol';
                    mso-bidi-font-family: 'Segoe UI Symbol';
                    mso-bidi-font-weight: bold;
                  "
                  > <% if (user.isResidential) { %>
              <span class="checked-checkbox">&#9745;</span>
              <% } else { %>
              <span class="unchecked-checkbox">&#9744;</span>
              <% } %></span
                ><span
                    style="
                      font-size: 8pt;
                      mso-bidi-font-size: 11pt;
                      color: black;
                      mso-color-alt: windowtext;
                    "
                    >Building<span style="letter-spacing: -0.45pt"> </span
                    ><span style="letter-spacing: -0.1pt">Inspector</span
                    ><span style="mso-tab-count: 1"> </span></span></b
                ><% if (user.isResidential) { %>
              <span class="checked-checkbox">&#9745;</span>
              <% } else { %>
              <span class="unchecked-checkbox">&#9744;</span>
              <% } %>
                <span
                    style="
                      font-size: 8pt;
                      mso-bidi-font-size: 11pt;
                      color: black;
                      mso-color-alt: windowtext;
                    "
                    >Water
                    <span style="letter-spacing: -0.1pt">Purveyor</span></span
                  >
              </p>
```

in my local host it is working and in dev checkbox is shrinked and it is not working how to fix it